# How can print multiple records of a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview, printing

How can I print multiple records of a listview?
The `PrintVisual` method prints only an image of a specific size or view
(where you stand at a time).

Can you please give me some suggestions as to how I could print multiple records using `PrintVisual` or any other method?

I am new to `WPF`, so please explain in brief if any one knows how to resolve this issue? (my listview is bound to another control)

Answer (score 0):

Use for loop

Ex:
for(int i=0; i< datagridview1.rows.count;i++)
{
    //Code for printing here
}